# How do I find a pattern and rename the file inserting a character between 2 parts of the matching pattern in the filename using prename?

Tags: regex, shell, find, rename

I am very close to having this working, this will for example work, but there is an additional space before and after the 0 chracter that I insert.
I am not sure how to take this space out and still have the variables correctly parse.

rename "3 - episode name" to "03 - episode name":

```
find . -type f -name '[[:digit:]] - [[:alpha:]]*' -execdir prename -n 's/(.*\/)(\d - \w.*)/$1 0 $2/g' {} +
```

Comment: You need to use the unambiguous backreference syntax, `${1}0$2`

Comment: works great, thank you! if you add that comment as answer I will accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the unambiguous backreference syntax, `${n}`, in the replacement pattern: `${1}0$2`.

```sh
find . -type f -name '[[:digit:]] - [[:alpha:]]*' -execdir prename -n 's/(.*\/)(\d - \w.*)/${1}0$2/' {} +
```

Note you need no `g` modifier here, you only perform a single replacement.

[image]